# failed to add quota to fstab something while installing ISPconfig on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: fstab, quota

```
[INFO] Adding quota to fstab.
[ERROR] Exception occured: ISPConfigOSException -> Command mount -o remount / 2>&1 && quotaoff -avug 2>&1 && quotacheck -avugm 2>&1 && quotaon -avug 2>&1 failed. (/ispconfig.ai.php:15)
```

what should I do?